# Solution to a PDE equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equations $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=-2fg$, for some non zero functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I read that the solutions of this equations are always of the form $f=\frac{F^{'}}{F+G}$, $g=\frac{G^{'}}{F+G}$, for some non constant functions $F=F(x)$, $G=G(y)$. I tried to solve the equations $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2fg$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=-2fg$, but I get and implicit dependence of $f$ from itself, and the same with $g$.

Now, these kind of functions fulfill the equations as I checked, but I can't prove that they are all.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $f_y - g_x = 0$. If you now introduce the vector function $F = (g,-f)^T$, you see that $\nabla \cdot F = \partial_x F_1 + \partial_y F_2 = 0$, i.e. $F$ is a [divergence-free vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field). That means that (e.g. using [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem)) this vector field has a *potential function* $V(x,y)$ such that $g = \partial_y V$ and $f = \partial_x V$. The PDE for $V$ is then
\begin{equation}
 \partial_{xy} V = -2 \,(\partial_x V) \,(\partial_y V). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now, assume that $V$ is positive, and write $V = \frac{1}{2} \log W$. Using $(1)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial_{xy} W}{W} = 0,
\end{equation}
which means that $\partial_{xy} W = 0$. Therefore, $W$ has the form
\begin{equation}
 W(x,y) = A(x) + B(y).
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
 f = \frac{1}{2} \frac{A'}{A+B} \;\text{and}\; g = \frac{1}{2} \frac{B'}{A+B}.
\end{equation}